# Using Like statement with Persian words

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have problem with Persian alphabet in SQL2008 R2 when I'm using Like statement...
I can search all worlds ...even 'ی' and 'ک' and I have some results but the problem is something like the font used for data inserted...
I meant when I enter word 'ک' like this line below then I have 26 results:

> Select * from EntityMethod where NamePersian like N'%ک%'

And when I enter word 'ك' like this line below I have 3 results:

> Select * from EntityMethod where NamePersian like N'%ك%'

In fact both 'ک' and 'ك' are exactly the same words but just their font is different.
The same problem is for 'ی' like all above...I dun know ,maybe it's not because of their font actually
I dun know how to solve this problem...

thanks anyway

Comment: I think font type has nothing to do with data saved in DB, probably with typing in your editor. 'ک' and 'ك' are the same `letter`. 'ك'  is used at end of a word and the letter 'ک' comes at the start of a word or in the middle of a word after a letter that cannot be bound to the next one after it. And btw this is `arabic` alphabet.

Comment: u know ...actually these two words are the same and they both are used at the end of the words...I took this example to understand easily...but when I use this two alphabet at any position of a word the I have different results..I have confused . I dun know why this has happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself :D...This problem has no solution but converting all database's data (text data) to the same format 'ک' in meeting with this case of both  'ك' and  'ک' together...
This problem occurs when Persian letters are in false position and keys on keyboard...also this problem is solvable by adding a component to "system32" folder in windows

Comment: Hello Fuad dear. please explain again more than you wrote beacuse i dont understand what should be changed in "System32"  and aslo how to change your data (which script  ?)

Comment: Sorry for delay dear Ali...You can search on google this key word "kbdfa.dll" , you will find all about it on searching and you will decide what to do . This is the file that you could copy it in "System32" to solve persian Keyboar.Also I said changing data...I meant changing 'ک' to 'ك' or 'ك' to 'ک'. because they are different letters ...this is what you have to decide that what conversion you need .if there is any question, let me know and ask again....